# Android ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5 ? firebase error

Tags: android, firebase, pusher

I'm trying to use the Pusher Beams API for push notifications. It said I need to integrate Firebase with my project first, but I keep getting the following error and none of the resources I found online have helped (which basically all call to play around with the firebase core versions)

ERROR: `Failed to resolve: com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5`

### ******* APP LEVEL BUILD.GRADLE **************

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.parse.starter"
    //        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
        implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'


        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
        implementation 'com.pusher:push-notifications-android:1.4.3'


    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

### *** PROJECT LEVEL BUILD.GRADLE *******

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 22
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

    minSdkVersion = 9
    targetSdkVersion = 23
}
```

**PROBLEM: the gradle refuses to sync. I've tried to clean/rebuild project/restart android studio, here's the sync error:**

this is the error when trying to sync the gradle:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: ParseStarterProject
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be coming from `com.pusher:push-notifications-android:1.4.4`. see the [build.gradle](https://github.com/pusher/push-notifications-android/blob/master/pushnotifications/build.gradle).
`com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5` had been deprecated (maybe removed from the Maven repository) and replaced with `androidx` [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/).

If you still need it, it's on [mavenCentral()](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher/0.8.5) repository.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your project level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    ...
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Firebase Docs

> You no longer need to add the Android library com.google.firebase:firebase-core

Try to remove `firebase-core` dependency and see. For more info, refer to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries)